# Using Word on Windows 10, unable to format highlighted text, keeps changing the whole document

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, alignment

When I try to change the alignment of individual paragraphs, its changes the whole document.

For example, I would like the title to be aligned to the right. Highlighting the text and clicking right align changes the whole text.

Also I have bullet point sections, and would like to indent these, but when I try to that, either with the indent button, or from the ruler, it again changes the whole document.

I have researched and tried changing a few different paragraph settings, but nothing has changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Are you using a custom template or custom styles on your document?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the alignment of an individual paragraph or title, you can use the paragraph buttons from the ribbon. It will change the whole paragraph though, not just the selected text. So your text needs to be in a separate paragraph for which you need to make sure to use hard returns between paragraphs. [Here is a link to the difference between hard and soft returns, and how to check if your text is in different paragraphs or not](https://www.chelseadatamanagement.com/when-to-use-soft-and-hard-returns-in-word/) (ctrl+* and look for paragraph markers).

When you want to change the indentation of one paragraph or bullet list, you can use the ruler. You can change either the page margin, the first line or the whole paragraph depending on what you shift on the ruler. Below are three examples.

Changing paragraph indentation by dragging the arrows to the right (click and hold the bottom part)
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3QSO.png)

Changing first line of paragraph by dragging only the top arrow to the right
[exmaple 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaU3s.png)

Changing the left margin of your pages by dragging the gray edge in the ruler
[example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDrEk.png)

To change the indentation of the bullet list with the ruler, select the whole list since every bullet is treated as a paragraph (check the paragraph markers with ctrl+*)